# Is there any memory leak in the following snip of code?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have the following snip of code:

```
int nWidth = 10;
int *pData = new int[nWidth];
//I do something here
//then I free memory by:
delete pData;
```

Do this snip of code produce a memory leak ?. Do I have to use:

```
delete[] pData;
```

Comment: Not only a memory leak, but a security hole.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't use `delete[] pData` the behavior is undefined. Could result in a memory leak, could crash the program, could run just fine until you demo your program for your most important customer.

Answer (score 7):

> Do this snip of code produce a memory leak ?

No, it has undefined behaviour, which is much worse.

> Do I have to use: `delete[] pData;`

Yes, all memory allocated with `new[]` must be freed with `delete[]`. However, it will still produce a memory leak if an early return or an exception prevents the program from reaching the delete expression.

Unless you're doing something unusual, there's rarely any need to manage memory explicitly. In this case, the standard library provides a convenient dynamic array type:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> data(nWidth);
// Do something here.
// Memory is freed automatically when data goes out of scope.
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you have to use:

```
delete[] pData;
```

Note the following points w.r.t dynamic allocations:

1. Avoid dynamic allocations as much as possible
2. You need to use `delete[]` if you allocated memory using `new[]`
3. You need to use `delete` if you allocated memory using `new`
4. You need to use `free()` if you allocated memory using `malloc()`
5. You need to pass the same address to the deallocating function which was returned by the allocating function in all the above 3<sup>[note]</sup>.

<sup>[note]</sup>
As correctly pointed out by David in his example in comments, an exception to the rule is Multiple inheritance where base class pointer may not have the same address as the subclass and passing the base class pointer address to `delete` instead of the subclass pointer address still shall work fine.

Comment: Point #5 is correct for memory allocated with `new[]` and `malloc()`. For memory allocated with `new`, the argument of `delete` can be a pointer to base class of the memory allocated with `new`. That base class pointer may or may not point to the same memory location as that returned by `new`.

Comment: @DavidHammen: That is not correct.The address being sent to deallocation function of any kind has to be the same returned by the corresponding allocation function else what you get is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: A pointer to some object and a base class pointer to that object doenot necessarily have same address (e.g., multiple inheritance). Per 5.3.5, para 2: "In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, **or a pointer to a subobject representing a base class of such an object**." Deleting from a base class pointer is okay, both by the new and old versions of the standard.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Can you please provide a code example which demonstrates your point.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Makes sense now.Your example demonstrates it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, and yes you do...

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, it is not a memory leak.